# If $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\ln(1+ax+x^2)}{\sqrt{x+b}-1}=2$, then what is $a+b$?

Tags: calculus, limits

> If $\lim_{x\to 0} \dfrac{\ln(1+ax+x^2)}{\sqrt{x+b}-1}=2$, $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$, and $\lambda=a+b$, $\lambda=?$

From class, my teacher told me, for this type of problem, to solve the limit as if I didn't know the answer, and at certain moments look for the values of the limit and check if it can be equal to $2$ (or whichever value the problem specifies). For instance, for something like $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt{ax^2+x+1} - x^2 = \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{(a-1)x^2 +x + 1}{x^2\left(\sqrt{a+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}} + 1\right)} =\begin{cases}0, \ a=1 \\ \infty, \ a > 1 \\ -\infty,\ a < 1\end{cases}$$
However, I'm not sure if this is possible here and I'm not quite sure how to start either. What I tried doing is $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\ln(1+ax+x^2)}{\sqrt{x+b}-1}=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\frac{\ln(1+ax+x^2)}{ax+x^2}\cdot(ax+x^2)}{\sqrt{x+b}-1} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{ax+x^2}{\sqrt{x+b}-1},$$ and I think this is "legal" because $\sqrt{x+b}-1$ as $x\to 0$ is not $0$? But even if I am able to substitute that part of the limit (which I'm sceptical about), I don't know how to continue. Any hints are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hint:   $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \ln (1+ax+x^2) = 0$, so for the whole thing to have non-zero limit one needs $b$ such that $\lim \sqrt{x+b}-1 = 0$.

Comment: $b\in \mathbb{R}$ or $b\in \mathbb{R}^+$?

Comment: @SineoftheTime just $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @blamocur by that logic, $b=1$, so the initial limit becomes $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln(1+ax+x^2}{\sqrt{x+a}-1}$. Then, is it as simple as applying L'Hopital once and finding that $\lim_{x\to 0}2\sqrt{x+1}(x+a)=2 \iff \sqrt{1}(a)=1 \iff a = 1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \dfrac{\ln(1+ax+x^2)}{\sqrt{x+b}-1}=2$$
Note that if $b\neq1$, the limit is $0$. So we must have $b=1$.
Now consider:
$${\lim_{x\to 0} \dfrac{\ln(1+ax+x^2)}{\sqrt{x+1}-1}=\lim_{x\to 0} \dfrac{\ln(1+ax+x^2)}{x}(\sqrt{x+1}+1)=\\ \lim_{x\to 0} \dfrac{\ln(1+ax+x^2)}{x}\lim_{x\to 0}(\sqrt{x+1}+1)}$$
So you have to find $a$ such that
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \dfrac{\ln(1+ax+x^2)}{x}=1 $$
Note that
$$ \dfrac{\ln(1+ax+x^2)}{x}= \dfrac{\ln(1+x(a+x))}{x(a+x)}(a+x)\to a \quad \text{as} \quad x \to 0$$
So also $a$ is $1$.

Comment: I see, I should've thought of the conjugate! Thank you for the solution!

Comment: You don't need the assumption $a\not=0$ as you divide by $a+x$ which is non-zero anyway.

Comment: @n3u1r0n you're right, I'll fix it

Answer (score 2):

The numerator always converges to $0$, so for the fraction to tend to $2$ the denominator must also converge to $0$, which implies $b=1$.
Now using that
$$
\sqrt{x+1}-1=\frac{x}{2}+O(x^2)
$$
and
$$
\log(1+ax+x^2)=ax+O(x^2),
$$
which one can easily get via the corresponding Taylor series, we have
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\log(1+ax+x^2)}{\sqrt{x+1}-1}
=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{ax}{\frac{x}{2}}=2a
$$
which implies $a=1$ as well.
So we have $\lambda=2$.

Comment: This seems like a very neat solution. Any places where I can learn more about these Taylor series and how to determine results such as yours, like $\frac{x}{2} + O(x^2)$? I am not too well acquainted with such concepts, besides something my professor called "Taylor theorem with Lagrange remainder," which I don't know if is related.

Comment: That's actually all you need!
Only that we don't need the exact remainder, only the order (the power of $x$) of it.
For the $f(x)=\sqrt{x+1}-1$ example all you need to know (more or less) is that $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)=1/2$ to get the Tailor expansion $f(x)=f(0)+f'(0)x+O(x^2)=x/2+O(x^2)$.
Rudin's Principles of mathematical analysis is probably a good starting point.